# S3 Post Policy key not honoring folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get S3 HTML uploads working, I'm trying to hard code define the key name rather than use the `${filename}`. This is controlled by my API server, but when I specify a key with folder separators and it's uploaded it's converted to its html entities of `%2F`.

So I have the POST Policy of this:

```
{
    "expiration": "2017-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "conditions": [ 
        {"bucket": "mybucket"},
        {"key": "i/1/1.png"},
        {"acl": "public-read"},
        {"Content-Type": "image/png"},
        ["content-length-range", "0", "1048576"]
    ]
}
```

Using the HTML form as so:

```
<html> 
  <head>
    <title>S3 POST Form</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body> 
    <form action="https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="key" value="i/1/1.png">
      <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="base64 policy">
      <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="signature">
      <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/png">
      <!-- Include any additional input fields here -->

      File to upload to S3: 
      <input name="file" type="file"> 
      <br> 
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3"> 
    </form> 
  </body>
</html>
```

When the file is uploaded it ends up with the file name of:

```
https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/i%2F1%2F1.png
```

So question is, how do I get `/` to be a literal folder separator?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm an idiot. I've learned that to S3 both `%2F` and `/` are valid folder separators.